# iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4 Screen sizing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

I have been developing a cocos2d app for the iPhone. I have been testing it solely on my iPhone 5. Everything looks great on it, but when I test it on the 3.5 inch simulator iPhone, some buttons go missing and some labels get misplaced.

I was wondering why this happens? I had thought that everything is positioned via the cocos2d grid which then converts it into pixels, so no matter the screen size the layout should look the same.

I think the problem might be due partly to the fact that when I set the position of a menu item, (0,0) puts it at the center of the screen. I don't know why this is.

Any advice on what is going on?

iPhone 5 on the left, simulator (3.5 inch) left.

[image]

Here is the code for this screen:

```
    CCSprite *title = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"highscoresTitle.png"];
    [self addChild:title];
    title.position = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width/2, [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height-title.contentSize.height-15);
    background.position = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width/2, [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height/2);
    play = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"playNew.png"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"playNew.png"] target:self selector:@selector(playScene:)];
    play.position = ccp(0, -200);

    CCLabelTTF *backLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"BACK" fontName:@"RBNo2-Light-Alternative" fontSize:25];
    CCMenuItemLabel *goBack = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:backLabel target:self selector:@selector(back:)];
    goBack.position = ccp(0, -260);

    CCMenuItemSprite *gameicon = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"gameCenter.png"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"gameCenter.png"] target:self selector:@selector(gameIcon:)];
    gameicon.position = ccp(0, -150);

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:play,goBack, gameicon, nil];
    [self addChild:menu z:0]; 

    for(int i = 0; i<5 && i<length; i++){

        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %d", i+1,[[highscores objectAtIndex:i]intValue]];
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:temp fontName:@"RBNo2-Light-Alternative" fontSize:20];
        label.position = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width/2, 350-i*30);
        label.visible = YES;
        [self addChild:label z:100 tag:1];

    }

    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Score: %d", newHighscore];
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:temp fontName:@"RBNo2-Light-Alternative" fontSize:20];
    label.position = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width/2, 415);
    label.visible = YES;
    [self addChild:label z:100 tag:1];
```

Here is another example with sliders: (iPhone 5 left)
[image]

And here is the code for the sliders:

```
    sliderCtl = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 460, 200, 0)];
    //[sliderCtl.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.141/2)];
    [sliderCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    sliderCtl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sliderCtl.value = 1.0;

    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:sliderCtl];

    sliderEff = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 402, 200, 0)];

    [sliderEff addTarget:self action:@selector(effectsSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    sliderEff.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sliderEff.value = 1.0;

    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:sliderEff];
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some code would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, this answer will disappoint you. iPhone 5 has a number of pixels along its long edge that is different from all previous models. The coordinate system you use for placing objects in your scene is point, where 1 pt equals 2 px on devices with Retina displays.

You do make use of `winSize` which is provided to you by the `CCDirector`. This indeed helps you calculating relative positions, for example in order to center along the horizontal as I see it in some places of your code, e.g. for `label`. You alone are responsible for positioning your objects, with some help from `anchorPoint`, `winSize`, and related properties.

**Specific example**: You place `goBack` at a relative position of -260 pt. Note that your `menu` is centered on the screen by default. On an iPhone 4S and every previous model, this means an absolute position of 480 pt / 2 - 260 pt = -20 pt. No surprise that button is off screen. You will have to test for `winSize.height` and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issues and am now using the UIDevice Extension library from GitHub at the following link to identify the device. This is a little overkill unless you use other items from the identified device besides just screen size but thought you might be able to use it since I tend to always run into more needs by device type.

https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension